# Angular4 karma proxy wildcard

Tags: angular, unit-testing, proxy, karma-runner

I have my api running on a server `myserver.com:4567/api` and I want every request from my angular app to go here when it matches /api/*. I've set this up already using a `proxy-conf.json` and it works perfectly for serving. However I want to test my application with karma, and it doesn't seem to accept wildcards for proxies.

How can I solve this without providing karma every possible endpoint

I want this:

```json
proxies: {
  "/api/*": "http://mybackend.com:4567"
}
```

instead of this:

```json
proxies: {
  "/api/1": "http://mybackend.com:4567/api/1"
  "/api/2": "http://mybackend.com:4567/api/2"
  "/api/3": "http://mybackend.com:4567/api/3"
  "/api/4": "http://mybackend.com:4567/api/4"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have figured out by now, Karma doesn't offer wildcards for proxy entries. However, when we have a look at how the proxying is accomplished, it turns out you can fake your endpoints with a file per endpoint and one proxy entry:

`proxies: {
  "/api": "/base/fake-api"
}`

Then you have a `fake-api` folder with contents, like so:

- **fake-api**

  - **some-other-route**

    - *other-result-1*
    - *other-result-2*
  - *1*
  - *2*
  - *3*
  - *4*

Where I have **subfolders** and *files* containing the results I  would like to fake from the api. I've been doing exactly this in a project to overcome the same problem. You'll also need a files entry like so:

`files:[
...
  { pattern: "fake-api/**/*", included: false, served: true, watched: false },
...
],`

(You may need to adjust the pathing to suit your desired layout; for example, I have my **fake-api** under my specs folder, so all the **fake-api** path parts above are actually **specs/fake-api** in my project, but you get the picture).

Comment: Thanks for this, this is somewhat better, but ideally I'd want to test with the actual backend (test backend), and not keeping a copy of each request.